# BindingResult in Spring boot not return anything if haserror

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, postman, spring-validator

I try to test the validation in my service for the fields, but when i put message for response not show the (message & status) in post man

I searched a lot in Stackoverflow no answer for my case

#### Entity:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String clientName;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    /** @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") **/ 
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String address;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String sex;

    @NotNull(message = "weight cannot be null")
    private Integer weight;

    @NotNull(message = "hight cannot be null")
    private Integer hight;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String healthNote;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String importantNote;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String personToContact;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String relation;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String phoneNumber;
```

#### Controller:

```java
    @PostMapping("/uploadProfileClient")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadMultipartFile(@Valid @RequestPart("addClient") String clientNew ,@Valid @RequestPart(value = "image")  MultipartFile image,BindingResult result) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {

    clientEntity client = null;
    Map<String,Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
      List<String> errors = result.getFieldErrors().stream().map(err -> "The field '" + err.getField() +"' "+ err.getDefaultMessage()) .collect(Collectors.toList());   
      response.put("Errors",errors);
      return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          client = mapper.readValue(clientNew, clientEntity.class);
          client.setImage(image.getBytes());

        try {
          clientService.save(client);
    } catch (  DataAccessException e) {
        response.put("message", "Error when inserting into the database");
        response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(response,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }  
        response.put("message", "the client data has been created successfully!");
        response.put("client", client);     
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(response,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

I will send data as json and file, the response no show in postman, please i need answer.

Comment: `@Valid` on a `String` doesn't do much. You will need to make that a `clientEntity` instead of a `String` and the `BindingResult` **MUST** directly follow the argument it applies to. I highly doubt that the `BindingResult` applies to the `MultipartFile`.

Comment: I try before clientEntity  not work and give errors, i get this solution from StackOverflow

Comment: Regardless, validating a `String` and `MultipartFile` are prettu much useless. So fix the error you have instead of trying something that won't work.

Comment: I can't find solution for send data with image from angular to spring boot just this way

Comment: Then ask that question instead of trying a solution that won't work.

Comment: No everything work with me no problem but the message in response no show in postman

Comment: Now you lost me. It doesn't work but it does? Your current solution will simply not work (validating a `String` and `MultipartFile` isn't going to do anything). If you are using the correct argument types and let Spring do the (de)serialization and validation it will work. If you submit invalid data (ie. string when number is required) you will get an exception and it will not reach your method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty straight forward, the `Weight` attribute accepts `Integer` but you are sending `"weight":"as"`, that is why you are getting `Deserialize` issue correct it.

Try with below, dummy data

```
{
   "clientName":"foo",
   "dateOfBirth":"2020-03-19",
   "mobileNumber":"9911",
   "email":"asd@email.com",
   "address":"sa",
   "sex":"m",
   "weight":"1",
   "hight":"12",
   "healthNote":"note",
   "importantNote":"imp",
   "personToContact":"myself",
   "relation":"single",
   "phoneNumber":"mynumber"
}
```

And also you don't have to manually convert the `string` to `Entity` using `ObjectMapper`. Spring can handle that so change the controller

```java
@PostMapping("/uploadProfileClient")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadMultipartFile(@Valid @RequestPart("addClient") ClientEntity clientNew ,@Valid @RequestPart(value = "image")  MultipartFile image,BindingResult result) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {
   //now you can save clientEntity directly

   client.setImage(image.getBytes());
   clientService.save(client);

  //your logic

}
```

#### Update

How to request from `PostMan`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, i try your solve, post man give me this message :                 "status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",

Comment: @MohamadAlhamid, you have to add headers in the `postman`, I will update the anser

Comment: For "weight":"as" i know it's integer i add string for test

Comment: I send my data as 'Content-Type': form-data

Comment: Ya it is a form data but you have to mention each file type, when you are trying to upload `body` with `Multipart`. May be if you go with `String` which you did,  you won't need that but you have to manually convert `string` to `class`

Comment: I thing no different, and i am send my data as form data it's work no problem but i want the response show

Comment: When send data with file from angular it's problem and @RequestBody no correct in this case, i get this solution from Stackoferflow